# Consider a Hilbert Space $H$ such that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \|x_n-y_n\| < 1.$ Show that if $z\perp y_n$ with $\forall n>0$ then $z=0$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

> Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space and $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ a
>   complete orthonormal set.  If $(y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence
>   such that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \|x_n-y_n\| < 1.$$ Show that if $z\perp y_n$ with $\forall n>0$ then $z=0$

Hi, can you help me with this exercise, I think in resolve it with Parseval's identity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\|z\|&=\left(\sum\left|\left<z,x_{n}\right>\right|^{2}\right)^{1/2}\\
&=\left(\sum\left|\left<z,x_{n}-y_{n}\right>+\left<z,y_{n}\right>\right|^{2}\right)^{1/2}\\
&=\left(\sum\left|\left<z,x_{n}-y_{n}\right>\right|^{2}\right)^{1/2}\\
&\leq\sum\left|\left<z,x_{n}-y_{n}\right>\right|\\
&\leq\sum\|z\|\|x_{n}-y_{n}\|\\
&=\|z\|\sum\|x_{n}-y_{n}\|,
\end{align*}
if $z\ne 0$, then we get a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you so much! Very fast your answer!

Comment: @user284331 How did you get the first inequality?

Comment: $(a^{2}+b^{2})^{1/2}\leq a+b$, some sort like this.